# Repeatedly write and read to/from QBuffer via QTextStream

Tags: c++, qt, read-write, qtextstream, qbuffer

I am trying to repeatedly write and read to/from a `QBuffer` object via `QTextStream`. First I construct both objects:

```
QBuffer b;
b.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite);
QTextStream s(&b);
// Setup text stream here
```

Then I write three different portions of information and read them back:

```
s << "Test" << 666 << endl << flush;
s.seek(0);
qDebug() << s.readAll();

s << "X" << endl << flush;
s.seek(0);
qDebug() << s.readAll();

s << "Test" << 777 << endl << flush;
s.seek(0);
qDebug() << s.readAll();
```

Of course I do not get the data portion I wrote immediately before, but the cumulated data:

```
"Test666\n"
"Test666\nX\n"
"Test666\nX\nTest777\n"
```

I could do adaptive seek calls to get the correct data but I do **not** want the `QBuffer` to **grow infinitely**.

I tried a `s.reset()` call between writes but the result is the same. Calling `reset()` or `open()/close()` directly on the buffer gives a crippled result (which is expected since the stream is bypassed):

```
"Test666\n"
"X\nst666\n"
"Test777\n"
```

I could probably build a new buffer for every cycle, open it and attach it to the stream but that is slow.

Is there a proper and fast solution for this use case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access `QBuffer`'s internal `QByteArray` storage directly with `QBuffer::buffer()` and then delete everything with `QByteArray::clear()`. Then manually `seek()` back to the start.

```cpp
    QBuffer b;
    b.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite);
    QTextStream s(&b);

    s << "Test" << 666 << endl << flush;
    s.seek(0);
    qDebug() << s.readAll();

    b.buffer().clear();
    s.seek(0);

    s << "X" << endl << flush;
    s.seek(0);
    qDebug() << s.readAll();

    b.buffer().clear();
    s.seek(0);

    s << "Test" << 777 << endl << flush;
    s.seek(0);
    qDebug() << s.readAll();
```

```
"Test666\n"
"X\n"
"Test777\n"
```

`QTextStream` also has a [constructor](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextstream.html#QTextStream-4) which takes a `QByteArray` directly and creates the `QBuffer` automatically, which may save a little code in this case.